# Which scheduler in python helps to run cron-type scheduling for one-time execution at a particular date and time?

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, cron, scheduler, jobs

I want to run a python cron-type scheduler and schedule a job for one time execution at a particular date and time. Once the job is done, the job has to disappear, while the scheduler still continues to run. Also looking for examples of using scheduler and storing jobs in mongodb or redis.

Answer (score 0):

You can use celery for this.Celery helps you run tasks in background and schedule cron jobs as well.
These docs state that you can

[schedule tasks to execute at a specific time](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/faq.html#module-celery.task.base)

[other useful resources](http://ask.github.io/celery/userguide/executing.html#eta-and-countdown).

Comment: were you able to figure out?

Comment: Got it. Thanks. Works.

Comment: Please do upvote and mark it as correct if it helps, thanks and happy programming!